# Trillion-row public dataset?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, google-bigquery, amazon-redshift

I am performing a few benchmarks on a database, and I was wondering if there are any publicly-available datasets that contain over 1T rows?

I know Google Big Query has a few publicly available datasets that are 100M+ (wikipedia, gdelt-events) and 1B+ (nyc-tlc) rows, but couldn't find anything larger. Does anyone know of a 1T-row dataset that can be either downloaded?

A few reference links:

- https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/
- https://cloud.google.com/public-datasets/

Comment: Doing a large amount of processing on a trillion row dataset could be expensive especially if you don't write your queries carefully. Do some calculations before you start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the benchmark wiki tables. It's got the biggest public table that I've seen. The largest table is 106B rows (6.76TB). If you really wanted a trillion rows, you could simply run ~10* copy append jobs!

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-samples:wikipedia_benchmark.Wiki100B?tab=details

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to just generate the dataset? Sure the question remains that how realistic its value distributions and co-correlations are, and how large impact this has on the measured performance.

And if you can assume that the cluster scales linearly you could just benchmark with 5% of data and 5% of the number of nodes you expect to have the production cluster. Regardless of the dataset size you just choose the number of nodes so that they can perform the needed number of requests / minute.

Taking a backup of that size database must be quite interesting problem, especially if it is constantly being updated.

Comment: Generating that much data would take a lot of time, and a lot of horsepower. $$$

Comment: It should still be cheaper than transferring it over the Internet and storing to secondary disks before storing it to your DB, assuming you don't do some real life simulation to generate the data. OTOH that Wikipedia benchmark table seems to compress really well!

Comment: The table/data is already in BigQuery. So, you're not transferring anything over the internet or storing to "secondary disks". You're running everything on Google's pipes/infrastructure i.e. on a petabit network.

Comment: I understood OP wanted to download the dataset and benchmark his own DB solution.

Comment: Turning into 100B rows table into a trillion row table would all be done on Google infrastructure. This would take about 30 mins. Then, if OP wanted to get that into his/her own DB, they could either export to GCS and download (correct, this would potentially be a bottleneck), or use Cloud Dataflow to read directly from BQ, and write to wherever, where everything would run on GCP. Fair point however!